# How to log errors in python when using the os module

Tags: python

I'm trying to incorporate a simple way to keep track of a periodic mysqldump command I want to run using the os module in python. I've written this, but in testing it doesn't raise the exception, even when the mysqldump command completes with an error. I'm pretty new to python, so I might be approaching this terribly, but I thought I would try to get pointed in the right direction.

```
db_dump = "mysqldump -u %s -p%s --socket=source_socket --databases %s | mysql -u %s -p%s   --socket=dest_socket" % (db_user, db_pass, ' '.join(db_list), db_user, db_pass)

try:
    os.system(db_dump)
except:
    logging.error("databases did not dump")
else:    
    logging.info("database dump complete")
```

Comment: write `logging`s output to a file [Using the logging python class to write to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386698/using-the-logging-python-class-to-write-to-a-file)

Comment: How do you start your logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.system()` returns an integer result code.  When it returns 0, the command ran successfully; when it returns a nonzero value, that indicates an error.

```
db_dump = "mysqldump -u %s -p%s --socket=source_socket --databases %s | mysql -u %s -p%s   --socket=dest_socket" % (db_user, db_pass, ' '.join(db_list), db_user, db_pass)

result = os.system(db_dump)
if 0 == result:
    logging.info("database dump complete")
else:
    logging.error("databases did not dump; result code: %d" % result)
```

Like @COpython, I recommend the use of `subprocess`.  It is a bit more complicated than `os.system()` but it is tremendously more flexible.  With `os.system()` the output is sent to the terminal, but with `subprocess` you can collect the output so you can search it for error messages or whatever.  Or you can just discard the output.

Comment: Thank you steveha for the quick and friendly response. I tried this and it worked, but I will research subprocess to see if that would be a better solution ultimately for this code.

Comment: With `os.system()` you get the exit status from the program you run.  You can look at the "man page" for the program to see what error it returns.  With `subprocess` you can get the exit status as well, but with `os.system()` that's all you get; you don't get an exception.

Answer (score 5):

os.system is not a very robust or powerful way to call system commands, I'd recommend using `subprocess.check_output()` or `subprocess.check_call`

ie,

```
>>> cmd = 'ls -l'
>>> badcmd = 'ls /foobar'
>>> subprocess.check_call(cmd.split())
0
>>> subprocess.check_call(badcmd.split())
ls: /foobar: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 511, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ls', '/foobar']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will research subprocess and try to convert my code to use it once I'm comfortable with it.

Comment: +1, but you shouldn't do `cmd.split()`. Just pass `cmd` as a string, and `subprocess` will break it up in a platform-appropriate way, taking into account quotes. (Of course it's better to have a list of args than a string in the first place—but if you do have a string, do not call `split` just to get a `list` of `args`.)

Comment: @numb3rs1x: It really doesn't take much to convert your code—just replace every use of `os.system` with `subprocess.check_call`. You could even just search-and-replace this. It won't exactly the same thing `os.system` did—instead, it will do *what you expected `os.system` to do*, which is better. (If you _do_ need anything fancy that `os.system` did, like passing shell expressions in the command, see the `shell=True` flag. But you probably don't.)

Comment: @abamert: I believe you need to `split()` the command unless you call it with `shell=True`

Comment: @abamert I've been playing around with the subprocess module, and it does seem to be the way to go for running a shell. I'm struggling with how to handle the exceptions is raises so they go into a log file of my choosing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do.

```
import logging
import subprocess
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

cmd = "mysqldump -u %s -p%s --socket=source_socket --databases %s | mysql -u %s -p%s " \
      "--socket=dest_socket" % (db_user, db_pass, ' '.join(db_list), db_user, db_pass)

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
stdout = [x for x in stdout.split("\n") if x != ""]
stderr = [x for x in stderr.split("\n") if x != ""]

if process.returncode < 0 or len(stderr):
    for error in stderr:
        log.error(error)
```

Comment: This looks a lot more advanced than I'm prepared for at my novice python level. I do thank you for contributing, and I'm looking forward to the day I when I have a better understanding of the intricacies of python programming.

Comment: Actually this isn't so bad.  All we do is shove your command into subprocess (which is a better os.system - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813238/difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-os-system).  Once we do that we wait for the results (communicate). Then split up the resulting lines into lines again, verify we got a good return and if not dump the output.