# Correct way to work with the `logging` module in Python

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to add logs to my code instead of printing everything. I read a bunch of other posts and articles, such as the ones listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386698/how-to-write-to-a-file-using-the-logging-python-module), but the logs in my code do not print.

Here's an example:

```
# driver.py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def main():
    logging.debug('This is a simple log')
    # other code here


if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

But my log does not print to `stdout`. What am I doing wrong?

Also, if I want to add logging to multiple files, can I configure the log on a separate file, import that file on my `driver.py` and `helper_funtions.py` for example, so I don't have to repeat the same thing over and over?

Comment: Add [`logging.basicConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) before any other logger config!

Answer (score 1):

You need a StreamHandler

```
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.add_handler(ch)
```

The logging cookbook provides plenty of examples on setting up streamhandlers as well as logging to a file. You can even configure the format of the logs to StdOut look different that that of the the file.

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook

Comment: not necessary. It worked by adding the `logging.basicConfig()` that @Klaus suggested