# Print specific string at the beginning of each line in log file

Tags: python, logging

How can I setup python's module `logging` so that every line it prints to the file starts with a specific string?

Comment: Refer [How to ask mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write to a file, using the logging Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386698/how-to-write-to-a-file-using-the-logging-python-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via the [log formatter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter). Here's a simple example configuring it via `logging.basicConfig`:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format="Hello at %(asctime)s %(message)s: %(levelname)s")
logging.warning("world")
```

Comment: So this makes sense, thanks. But the string that I want to print is the time of printing. So how can I make the 'hello' be a variable?

Comment: Ah, well check the documentation. But I'll add a timestamp to my example.

Answer (score 0):

> Using python logging

**Formatting the Output**

You can pass any variable that can be represented as a string from your program as a message to your logs. If you for example want to log the process ID along with the level and message, you can do something like this:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(process)d-%(levelname)s-%(message)s')
logging.warning('This is a Warning')

# Output:
# 18472-WARNING-This is a Warning
```

*For further details see [documentation](https://realpython.com/python-logging/) on realpython.*