# How to write logs to file

Tags: python, logging

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,filename=r"path\Logs.txt",format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',filemode='a')
```

Its printing in the console instead of writing to a file.

I am expecting it to be written to a log file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write to a file, using the logging Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386698/how-to-write-to-a-file-using-the-logging-python-module)

Comment: `basicConfig` only works if no logging has been configured already. Is there any logging configured before this call?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to write debug log after setting log level to info, it will not be written. Try writing info and warning logs. As below:

```
logging.info("Info Log")
logging.warn("Warning Log")
logging.debug("Debug Log")   #It will not be written in your log file
```

Comment: Hi @sushanta Das. Even after changing its written in the console instead of writing it to a file

Comment: logger = logging.getLogger(**__name__**)
logger.propagate = False
#Add this part in your code before writing the log message to file, this might solve
#Are you importing any python module in your code apart from logging

Comment: It didnt work i tried everything its printing in the console and its not wiriting into the log file