# Change default behavior of uncaught exception handling in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, sys

I went through "[Logging uncaught exceptions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234405/logging-uncaught-exceptions-in-python)". And, I have tried this:

```
import web
import sys

app = web.application((
  '/test', 'test'), globals())

def test_func(e_type, value, traceback):
  print "Handled exception here.."

class test:
  def GET(self):
    a = 1/0

if __name__ == "__main__":
  sys.excepthook = test_func
  app.run()
```

Here, you can easily see if `GET /test` request comes in, I am deliberately raising `ZerDivisionError`. As i have overriden `sys.excepthook`, I expect method `test_func` to execute on `ZeroDivisionError`.

Whereas, this piece of code is not working as per expectation. I have observed that when i try to override `excepthook` in standalone code (not in web-app), it works fine. New method(overriden) is called properly.

Any idea why is this different behavior ?

Comment: Which web app are you using? The most likely reason is that the web-app has decided that this is too dangerous a feature to allow you to play with.

Comment: I did not get 'which web-app?' I am using web.py here. And i have for example written a small web service here, exposing /test.

Answer (score 6):

Using web.py, one way of catching exceptions yourself would be to [add a custom processor](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/api#web.application):

```
...
def error_processor(handler):
   try:
       handler()
   except:
       # do something reasonable to handle the exception
       return 'something happened...'

app.add_processor(error_processor)
app.run()
...
```

Otherwise web.py will catch the exception and show a default error message instead.

Comment: Thanks @mata I tried this one. The problem with this is, if something goes wrong in the code then the exception catched is '500 Internal Server Error'. I want actual exception / error thrown from the code. Any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Seems like only instances of HTTPError are re-reaised [when calling the processors](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/32c891c64bd838ad972239f81254fdfb0c784bf4/web/application.py#L232), everything else is converted to a blank internalError, so this unfortunately will only work for HTTPErrors.

Comment: anyother solution you can think of? Or shall  I go ahead and do the changes in web.py itself ? I don't prefer the second one.

Comment: I can't really think of an ohter solution. I agree, changing the source of an external library isn't a really good way, in such cases I prefer to monkeypatch it. [here](http://pastebin.com/iXKnJF1P) I've prepared a small example on how this could work for that case, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @mata for apt reply. Yes, monkeypatching is a good idea and makes sense. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 3):

Python doc says

> sys.excepthook(type, value, traceback)
>
> This function prints out a given traceback and exception to sys.stderr.

So this `sys.excepthook` is called when a exception needs to printed to terminal. Now you see, web.py itself handles the exceptions. If you dont assign the sys.excepthook, webpy captures the exception and shows the exception in browser. And as web.py is itself handling the exceptions, setting `sys.excepthook` makes no change.
If web.py didn't handle the exception itself, then it would be uncaught and `sys.excepthook` would be called.

If you really want to handle exception yourself in this code, try searching web.py doc and source code to figure out how web.py handles exceptions and customize that.

python doc also says

> `sys.__excepthook__`
>
> These objects contain the original values of displayhook and excepthook at the start of the program. They are saved so that displayhook and excepthook can be restored in case they happen to get replaced with broken objects.

So my guess is web.py using that, so your custom handler is not called.