# how to use atexit when exception is raised

Tags: python

i have a scenario where some unknown `exceptions` may be raised during program execution and i can't `except` most of them and i want every time any `exception` will raise an email should send to me as `exceptions` cause program to terminate if not properly catch!

so i have read about `python` provide `atexit` module but it did not work with `exceptions` so my question is , is there any way to make `atexit` work with `exceptions`?? so every any exception raised and programs terminates it should send me a mail?
thanks

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234405/logging-uncaught-exceptions-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at `sys.excepthook`. As its name suggests, it's a hook into the exception. You can use it to send you an email when exceptions are raised.