# How can I make nginx/gunicorn use structured logging?

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn

I currently see

```
172.19.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2018:07:00:32 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "-" "curl/7.47.0"
```

within my logs, but I use [structured logging like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48202500/562769).

I even tried

```
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setFormatter(pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter())
logging.getLogger("urllib3").addHandler(ch)
```

but I still see those messages. I have nginx/gunicorn like this ([source](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/container/decision_trees/serve)):

```
nginx = subprocess.Popen(['nginx', '-c', '/opt/program/nginx.conf'])
gunicorn = subprocess.Popen(['gunicorn',
                             '--timeout', str(model_server_timeout),
                             '-k', 'gevent',
                             '-b', 'unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock',
                             '-w', str(model_server_workers),
                             'server.wsgi:app'])
```

I guess this is where the log messages come from. But I have no idea how to get structured logging there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. I had to edit the `nginx.conf`:

Within `http`:

```
log_format structured '{"remote_addr": "$remote_addr", "remote_user": "$remote_user", "request": "$request", "status": $status, "body_bytes_sent": $body_bytes_sent, "http_referer": "$http_referer", "http_user_agent": "$http_user_agent"}';
```

and within `http > server`:

```
access_log /dev/stdout structured;
```

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html

Now the messages look like this:

```
{
    "remote_addr": "10.32.0.2",
    "remote_user": "-",
    "request": "GET /ping HTTP/1.1",
    "status": 200,
    "body_bytes_sent": 1,
    "http_referer": "-",
    "http_user_agent": "AHC/2.0"
}
```

### Still TODO

It would be nice if the request was

```
{"method": "GET",
 "endpoint": "/ping",
 "protocol": "HTTP/1.1"}
```

Comment: You can answer the `TODO` part with the following variables:
```{ "method": "$request_method", "endpoint": "$request_uri", "protocol": "$server_protocol" }```

Answer (score 1):

The logging format set in Python process has nothing to do with the one in Nginx and Gunicorn.

If you want to set Nginx logging format, see

https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/#access_log

For gunicorn, see http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#access-log-format

Comment: From the log message above: What is the part created by gunicorn? How do I make it a structured log?

Comment: I guess the above log is captured by gunicorn, looks very like the default format. set `--access-logformat` to `'{"remote_addr": %(h)s...}'` as you like

Comment: + link http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#access-log-format

Comment: look at my answer. As I almost completely solved it with nginx config, it for sure is mostly nginx. only the "request" part might be gunicorn