# Python logging into file as a dictionary or JSON

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to set up logging where I can log in both stdout and on to a file. This i have accomplished using the following code:

```
logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
        datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', handlers=[logging.FileHandler(path), logging.StreamHandler()])
```

The output of this something like this:

```
2018-05-02 18:43:33,295 DEBUG    Starting new HTTPS connection (1): google.com
2018-05-02 18:43:33,385 DEBUG    https://google.com:443 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 220
2018-05-02 18:43:33,389 DEBUG    Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.google.com
2018-05-02 18:43:33,490 DEBUG    https://www.google.com:443 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

What I am trying to accomplish is logging this output to a file not as it is printing to stdout, but as a dictionary or JSON object similar to something like this (while keeping the stdout as it is at the moment):

`[{'time': '2018-05-02 18:43:33,295', 'level': 'DEBUG', 'message': 'Starting new HTTPS connection (1): google.com'}, {...}, {...}]`

Is this doable? I understand that I can post process this log file after my process is finished, but I am looking for a more elegant solution because certain things i am logging are quite big objects themselves.

Comment: This I have considered @Sphinx, but this doesnt work because then it will print to stdout as a json schema

Comment: What you want to do is create a custom `Formatter` that takes a `LogRecord` and JSON-encodes it (maybe preprocessing it first, of course). Then you create a stdout handler that uses the default formatter, and a file handler that uses your custom formatter. This isn't entirely trivial, but the [Advanced Logging Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial) should get you started, and [some sections of the Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#use-of-alternative-formatting-styles) have some relevant-ish sample code.

Comment: There are also a variety of pre-made structured-logging libraries on PyPI. I don't know which ones are any good or which features they each have, but I wouldn't be surprised if there's one that does what you want with a bit of minor configuration instead of writing a bunch of code.

Comment: One last thing: You can't just "write JSON to a file". Well, you _can_ (as long as your top-level texts are always objects or arrays), but most JSON-parsing code won't handle an arbitrary stream of JSON texts in a single file. You want to use something like [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/), or one of the two near-identical formats, which slightly restrict what's allowed in JSON encoding so you can guarantee exactly one JSON text ends up on each line of a text file.

Comment: @abarnert I am exploring the advanced section of the cookbook at the moment. It seems that would be workable. Maybe. I am not sure how it will handle a big JSON object I am already logging, but here goes trying. Thanks!

Comment: @securisec Embedding a big JSON object inside another JSON object should just work, whether you store it as a dict value, or encode it to a JSON text and make it a string value. The second one will obviously be less human-readable, but I assume you're dumping to JSON because you want to process it with software, not read it in less.

Comment: @securisec Meanwhile, if you get something working, and then you can condense it down to an example that would help other people, you should write and accept an answer to your own question.

Comment: Will do @abarnert. I am exploring your first answer regarding setting two formatters, but you are right on your third answer; it is being a pain to work with the output in JSON format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can structured logging be done with Pythons standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170682/can-structured-logging-be-done-with-pythons-standard-library)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So based on @abarnert, i found this [Link](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html) which provided a good path to making this concept work for the most part. The code as it stands is:

```
logger=logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

file_handler=logging.FileHandler('foo.log')
stream_handler=logging.StreamHandler()

stream_formatter=logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
file_formatter=logging.Formatter(
    "{'time':'%(asctime)s', 'name': '%(name)s', \
    'level': '%(levelname)s', 'message': '%(message)s'}"
)

file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
stream_handler.setFormatter(stream_formatter)

logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
```

Although it does not fully meet the requirement, it doesnt require any pre processing, and allows me to create two log handlers.

Afterwards, i can use something like:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('foo.log') as f:
    for line in f:
        for key, value in literal_eval(line):
            do something ...
```

to pull `dict` objects instead of fighting with improperly formatted JSON to accomplish what I had set out to accomplish.

Still am hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, the output data is not valid json data. `json.load("{'time':'2020-11-04 15:42:30,193', 'name': 'Jack\"s'}")`

Comment: Be careful. Your solution will break if your message has a single quote.

Comment: @overgroove, to resolve this I just used json.dumps and removed the quotes. `import json` and `file_formatter=logging.Formatter(json.dumps({'time':'%(asctime)s', 'name': '%(name)s', 'level': '%(levelname)s', 'message': '%(message)s'}))`

Comment: @deesolie ... or simply creating your own formatter that does this `json.dumps` thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77064730/1603480

Anyway, this solution is not ideal and should probably not marked as accepted answer as such.

Answer (score 37):

I too dealt with this and I personally believe that an external library might be an overkill for something like this.

I studied a bit the code behind **logging.Formatter** and came up with a subclass which in my case does the trick (my goal was to have a JSON file that Filebeat can read to further log into ElasticSearch).

## Class:

```
import logging
import json


class JsonFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    """
    Formatter that outputs JSON strings after parsing the LogRecord.

    @param dict fmt_dict: Key: logging format attribute pairs. Defaults to {"message": "message"}.
    @param str time_format: time.strftime() format string. Default: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
    @param str msec_format: Microsecond formatting. Appended at the end. Default: "%s.%03dZ"
    """
    def __init__(self, fmt_dict: dict = None, time_format: str = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", msec_format: str = "%s.%03dZ"):
        self.fmt_dict = fmt_dict if fmt_dict is not None else {"message": "message"}
        self.default_time_format = time_format
        self.default_msec_format = msec_format
        self.datefmt = None

    def usesTime(self) -> bool:
        """
        Overwritten to look for the attribute in the format dict values instead of the fmt string.
        """
        return "asctime" in self.fmt_dict.values()

    def formatMessage(self, record) -> dict:
        """
        Overwritten to return a dictionary of the relevant LogRecord attributes instead of a string. 
        KeyError is raised if an unknown attribute is provided in the fmt_dict. 
        """
        return {fmt_key: record.__dict__[fmt_val] for fmt_key, fmt_val in self.fmt_dict.items()}

    def format(self, record) -> str:
        """
        Mostly the same as the parent's class method, the difference being that a dict is manipulated and dumped as JSON
        instead of a string.
        """
        record.message = record.getMessage()
        
        if self.usesTime():
            record.asctime = self.formatTime(record, self.datefmt)

        message_dict = self.formatMessage(record)

        if record.exc_info:
            # Cache the traceback text to avoid converting it multiple times
            # (it's constant anyway)
            if not record.exc_text:
                record.exc_text = self.formatException(record.exc_info)

        if record.exc_text:
            message_dict["exc_info"] = record.exc_text

        if record.stack_info:
            message_dict["stack_info"] = self.formatStack(record.stack_info)

        return json.dumps(message_dict, default=str)
```

## Usage:

The formatter must simply be passed to the logging handler.

```
    json_handler = FileHandler("foo.json")
    json_formatter = JsonFormatter({"level": "levelname", 
                                    "message": "message", 
                                    "loggerName": "name", 
                                    "processName": "processName",
                                    "processID": "process", 
                                    "threadName": "threadName", 
                                    "threadID": "thread",
                                    "timestamp": "asctime"})
    json_handler.setFormatter(json_formatter)
```

## Explanation :

While the **logging.Formatter** takes a string which it interpolates to output the formatted log record, the JsonFormatter takes a dictionary where the key will be the key of the logged value in the JSON string and the value is a string corresponding to an attribute of the LogRecord that can be logged.
(List available in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes))

Main *"problem"* would be parsing dates and timestamps, and the default formatter implementation has these class attributes, *default_time_format* and *default_msec_format*.

default_msec_format gets passed to **time.strftime()** and default_msec_format is interpolated to append miliseconds as time.strftime() doesn't provide formatting options for those.

The principle is that those are now instance attributes which can be provided in the form of **time_format** and **msec_format** to customize how the parent's class (unchanged, as it's not overwritten) **formatTime()** method behaves.

You could technically override it if you want to customize time formatting, but I personally found that using something else would either be redundant or limit the actual formatting options. But feel free to adjust as to your needs.

## Output:

An example JSON record logged by the formatting options above, with the default time formatting options set in the class, would be:

```
{"level": "INFO", "message": "Starting service...", "loggerName": "root", "processName": "MainProcess", "processID": 25103, "threadName": "MainThread", "threadID": 4721200640, "timestamp": "2021-12-04T08:25:07.610Z"}
```

Comment: As an extension (since hostname is not in the logging spec), I changed `formatMessage` to return `{fmt_key: host if fmt_key == "host" else record.__dict__[fmt_val] for fmt_key, fmt_val in self.fmt_dict.items()}`, after also adding `import platform` and `host = platform.node()` at the beginning of the file. I find this very handy when sending logs from multiple hosts and consuming centrally, such as filebeat into elastisearch or similar. (I'm no pythonista, there's likely a much better way to do this.) (Add `"host":""` to the instantiation of `jsonFormatter`.)

Comment: @r2evans I'm definitely planning to do it in a way that you have written, just to prepare data for logstash. I don't want to write formatter/parsers in logstash, my main backend is python and I want to structure the logging data beforehand(before the logstash). So I'm adding custom parameters like host, ip, some browser activities that frontend app sends during hit of api.

Answer (score 4):

I could achieve this result using this custom formatter:

```py
import json
import logging


class CustomJsonFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> str:
        super(CustomJsonFormatter, self).format(record)
        output = {k: str(v) for k, v in record.__dict__.items()}
        return json.dumps(output)


cf = CustomJsonFormatter()
sh = logging.StreamHandler()
sh.setFormatter(cf)

logger = logging.getLogger("my.module")
logger.addHandler(sh)

# simple json output
logger.warning("This is a great %s!", "log")
# enrich json output
logger.warning("This is an even greater %s!", "log", extra={'foo': 'bar'})
```

Output:

```json
{"name": "my.module", "msg": "This is a great %s!", "args": "('log',)", "levelname": "WARNING", "levelno": "30", "pathname": "/Users/olivier/test.py", "filename": "test.py", "module": "test", "exc_info": "None", "exc_text": "None", "stack_info": "None", "lineno": "20", "funcName": "<module>", "created": "1661868378.5048351", "msecs": "504.8351287841797", "relativeCreated": "1.3060569763183594", "thread": "4640826880", "threadName": "MainThread", "processName": "MainProcess", "process": "81360", "message": "This is a great log!"}
{"name": "my.module", "msg": "This is an even greater %s!", "args": "('log',)", "levelname": "WARNING", "levelno": "30", "pathname": "/Users/olivier/test.py", "filename": "test.py", "module": "test", "exc_info": "None", "exc_text": "None", "stack_info": "None", "lineno": "22", "funcName": "<module>", "created": "1661868378.504962", "msecs": "504.9619674682617", "relativeCreated": "1.4328956604003906", "thread": "4640826880", "threadName": "MainThread", "processName": "MainProcess", "process": "81360", "foo": "bar", "message": "This is an even greater log!"}
```

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to have JSON output, so that I could handle it nicer in Promtail and Loki. I just updated the formatter in my logging.json, which I use as a dictConfig

```
"formatters": {
    "normalFormatter": {
        "format": "{\"time\": \"%(asctime)s\", \"name\": \"[%(name)s]\", \"levelname\": \"%(levelname)s\", \"message\": \"%(message)s\"}"
    }
}
```

Load the config and get the root logger like:

```
import json
import logging


# setup logger
with open("logging.json") as f:
    config_dict = json.load(f)
    logging.config.dictConfig(config_dict)

# get root logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

If you want to use dictConfig, please make sure you gave all necessary fields.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html

You may want to define a formatter, a handler (which is using the formatter) and the logger (which is using the handler)

e.g. logging.json

```
{
"version": 1,
"disable_existing_loggers": false,
"formatters": {
    "normalFormatter": {
        "format": "{\"time\": \"%(asctime)s\", \"name\": \"[%(name)s]\", \"levelname\": \"%(levelname)s\", \"message\": \"%(message)s\"}"
    }
},
"handlers": {
    "demohandler": {
        "level": "INFO",
        "formatter": "normalFormatter",
        "class": "logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler",
        "filename": "./files/logs/YourLogFile.log",
        "when": "d",
        "interval": 30,
        "backupCount": 4,
        "utc": true
    }
},
"loggers": {
    "root": {
        "handlers": ["demohandler"],
        "level": "INFO"
    },
    "someModule": {
        "handlers": ["demohandler"],
        "level": "INFO",            
        "propagate": 0
    }        
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With this code you can add the full traceback, timestamp and level to a json file of choice.

```py
import json
import traceback
from datetime import datetime

def addLogging(logDict:dict):
    loggingsFile = 'loggings.json'

    with open(loggingsFile) as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    data.append(logDict)

    with open(loggingsFile, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)

def currentTimeUTC():
    return datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

try:
    print(5 / 0)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    fullTraceback = str(traceback.format_exc())
    addLogging({'timestamp': currentTimeUTC(), 'level': 'error', 'traceback': fullTraceback})
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": "09/06/2020 17:38:00",
        "level": "error",
        "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"d:testFullTraceback.py\", line 19, in <module>\n    print(5/0)\nZeroDivisionError: division by zero\n"
    }
]
```

Comment: So here you have to explicitly call addLogging() in every exception handler?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to create it using [python-json-logger](https://github.com/madzak/python-json-logger) lib, it was simple and really easily to use.

**Django**

```py
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger

##This is to add custom keys
class CustomJsonFormatter(jsonlogger.JsonFormatter):
    def add_fields(self, log_record, record, message_dict):
        super(CustomJsonFormatter, self).add_fields(log_record, record, message_dict)
        log_record['level'] = record.levelname


# Logging
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'json': {
            '()': CustomJsonFormatter, # if you want to use custom logs class defined above
            # '()': jsonlogger.JsonFormatter, # without custom logs
            'format': '%(level)s %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s %(threadName)s %(special)s %(run)s\
                %(name)s %(created)s %(processName)s %(relativeCreated)d %(funcName)s %(levelno)d %(msecs)d %(pathname)s %(lineno)d %(filename)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'json' 
        },
    },
    .....
}
```

**Flask**

```
from logging.config import dictConfig
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger
import os

# This will set global root logging config across all the modules using in the app

##This is to add custom keys
class CustomJsonFormatter(jsonlogger.JsonFormatter):
    def add_fields(self, log_record, record, message_dict):
        super(CustomJsonFormatter, self).add_fields(log_record, record, message_dict)
        log_record['level'] = record.levelname


def setup():
    LOG_FILE = '/tmp/app/app.json'
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(LOG_FILE)):  # if LOG_FILE dir doesn't exist, creates it.
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(LOG_FILE))
    dictConfig({
        'version': 1,
        'formatters': {
            'default': {
                'format': '%(asctime)s - %(module)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
            },
            'json': {
            '()': CustomJsonFormatter, # if you want to use custom logs class defined above
            # '()': jsonlogger.JsonFormatter, # without custom logs
            'format': '%(level)s %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s %(threadName)s %(special)s %(run)s\
                %(name)s %(created)s %(processName)s %(relativeCreated)d %(funcName)s %(levelno)d %(msecs)d %(pathname)s %(lineno)d %(filename)s'
        },
        },
        'handlers': {'file': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': LOG_FILE,
            'maxBytes': 10485760,
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'json'
        },
        'console':{
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'json'
        }},
        'root': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['file', 'console']
        }
    })
```

Hope this helps easy way setup.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind pip installing a module to help, there is the [json_log_formatter](https://pypi.org/project/JSON-log-formatter/) module. The json output does have more attributes than requested. The [repo](https://github.com/marselester/json-log-formatter) mentions customizing the attributes outputted, but I have not yet integrated that into a working example just yet.

### json_log_formatter

```
import logging
import json_log_formatter

# Set Basic Logging 
self.loggers = logging.getLogger(__name__)
self.loggers.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
self.formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', datefmt = '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')


# Config for JSON File Handler
self.logFileHandler = logging.FileHandler(SOME-PATH, mode='a')
self.fileFormatter = json_log_formatter.VerboseJSONFormatter()
self.logFileHandler.setFormatter(self.fileFormatter)
self.logFileHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
self.loggers.addHandler(self.logFileHandler)


# Config for Stream Handler
self.logStreamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
self.logStreamHandler.setFormatter(self.formatter)
self.logStreamHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
self.loggers.addHandler(self.logStreamHandler)
```

Comment: Alternatively, just use @securisec answer and used json.dumps to resolve any quote issues. This worked the best for me, but I am keeping this post for others to use if they choose. `import json` and `file_formatter=logging.Formatter(json.dumps({'time':'%(asctime)s', 'name': '%(name)s', 'level': '%(levelname)s', 'message': '%(message)s'}))`

Answer (score 1):

You could also design a simple formatter like this one (which basically create a dictionary and serialises it to JSON format).

Then adding a handler dumping to a file with this formatter and a regular handler to print in the console and you are good to go.

Here is an example where I want to load all data in a Pandas DataFrame after execution:

```
import json
import logging
from logging import LogRecord

import pandas as pd


class JsonFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    """Formatter to dump error message into JSON"""

    def format(self, record: LogRecord) -> str:
        record_dict = {
            "level": record.levelname,
            "date": self.formatTime(record),
            "message": record.getMessage(),
            "module": record.module,
            "lineno": record.lineno,
        }
        return json.dumps(record_dict)



logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

json_h = logging.FileHandler("errors.ndjson", mode="w")
formatter = JsonFormatter()
json_h.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(json_h)

stream_h = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_h.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(message)s"))
logger.addHandler(stream_h)


logger.error("""some error with "double quotes" and 'single quotes'""")
logger.critical("some critical text")
logger.warning("some warning")
logger.info("some info")

df = pd.read_json("errors.ndjson", lines=True)
print(df.dtypes)  # type: ignore
print(df)
```

You coud also use the dedicated module [Python JSON Logger](https://pypi.org/project/python-json-logger/):

```
...
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger


log_format = "%(asctime)s - %(module)s#%(lineno)d - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
formatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter(
    fmt=log_format, rename_fields={"levelname": "level", "asctime": "date"}
)

logger = logging.getLogger()

json_h= logging.FileHandler("errors.ndjson", mode="w")
json_h.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(json_h)
...
```

Note that the simple implementation has the following limitations compared to `python-json-logger`:

- a hard-coded choice of attributes (but this could be parametrized via an argument of the Formatter class)
- no support of Traceback / Exception (i.e. `exc_info`)
- does not display `extra` information (like for example in `logger.info("message", extra={"field": "value"}`)

**Output**:

```json
{"level": "ERROR", "date": "2023-09-08 15:05:26,816", "message": "some error with \"double quotes\" and 'single quotes'", "module": "try_json_logger", "lineno": 50}
{"level": "CRITICAL", "date": "2023-09-08 15:05:26,816", "message": "some critical text", "module": "try_json_logger", "lineno": 51}
{"level": "WARNING", "date": "2023-09-08 15:05:26,816", "message": "some warning", "module": "try_json_logger", "lineno": 52}
{"level": "INFO", "date": "2023-09-08 15:05:26,816", "message": "some info", "module": "try_json_logger", "lineno": 53}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to save full LogRecord object, so I can later inspect my log with maximum of integration with module. So I inspected object like that:

```
from logging import Handler, LogRecord, getLogger

class HandlerJson(Handler):

    def emit(self, record: LogRecord) -> None:
        json_data = {}
        for attr in filter(lambda attr: not attr.endswith("__"), dir(record)):
            json_data[attr] = record.__getattribute__(attr)
        del json_data["getMessage"]
        print(json_data)
```

This is subclass of `Handler`, `emit` is a rewritten method that is been called with every `LogRecord`. `Dir` returns all attributes and methods of the object. I am excluding special methods, and also deleting getMessage method, whitch is not needed for json object representation.

This can be nicely integrated in logging like that:

```
logger = getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(DEBUG)
handle_json = HandlerJson()
logger.addHandler(handle_json)

logger.info("my info")
```

result looks like this:

```
{
'args': (),
'created': 1639925351.0648422,
'exc_info': None,
'exc_text': None,
'filename': 'my_logging.py',
'funcName': 'restore_log_from_disk',
'levelname': 'INFO',
'levelno': 20,
'lineno': 142,
'module': 'my_logging',
'msecs': 64.84222412109375,
'msg': 'my info',
'name': '__main__',
'pathname': 
'/home/jindrich/PycharmProjects/my_logging.py',
'process': 146331,
'processName': 'MainProcess',
'relativeCreated': 1.6417503356933594,
'stack_info': None,
'thread': 140347192436544,
'threadName': 'MainThread'
}
```

Then you can load data from disk and recreat objects after some digging in doc.

Comment: Instead of creating a dict and populating with a loop with a filter, it would be cleaner to use dictionary comprehention: `json_data = {a: getattr(record, a) for a in dir(record) if not a.endswith("__")}`. And globally, it seems easier to create a Formatter than a Handler.