# How to handle optional arguments in logging format strings?

Tags: python, logging

I would like to use the following log format:

```python
'format': '{"message": "%(message)s", "user": "%(user)s"}'
```

However, I would like to call it in two different ways:

```python
log.info("hi", extra={"user": "asmith"})
log.info("hi")
```

The first log statement works because it provides the `user` argument, but the second one fails with a `KeyError`.

Is there any way to make a format string argument optional?

Comment: Off the top of my head I think you'll have to write yourself a custom Formatter that knows how to respond if it gets a `KeyError`, but there might be an easier way.

Comment: What's wrong with `extra={"user": None}`?

Comment: @Bakuriu sometimes I'll be calling this from outside the application -- so for backwards compatibility as well.

Comment: See this [`CustomAdapter`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-loggeradapters-to-impart-contextual-information) example in the logging cookbook. You can use `self.extra.get('user')` to default it to `None` when not supplied.

Comment: It looks like OP was attempting to log in JSON format, what is done over here with string interpolation is likely to produce invalid JSON. See: [Python logging into file as a dictionary or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144628/python-logging-into-file-as-a-dictionary-or-json) if you want to do that.

Answer (score 15):

### Optional format args replaced with `None`

Given a fixed logging format string, a custom `Formatter` class can be used to replace missing arguments with `None`.

```python
import logging
import re

class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    def format(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> str:
        arg_pattern = re.compile(r'%\((\w+)\)')
        arg_names = [x.group(1) for x in arg_pattern.finditer(self._fmt)]
        for field in arg_names:
            if field not in record.__dict__:
                record.__dict__[field] = None

        return super().format(record)


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = CustomFormatter('{"message": "%(message)s", "user": "%(user)s"}')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.info('hi')
logger.info('hi', extra={"user": "asmith"})
```

**Output**

```
{"message": "hi", "user": "None"}
{"message": "hi", "user": "asmith"}
```

### Dynamically add extra args to logging output

A custom `Formatter` can dynamically update the format string based on the dictionary passed to `extra`.

```python
import logging

class ExtraFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    def format(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> str:
        default_attrs = logging.LogRecord(None, None, None, None, None, None, None).__dict__.keys()
        extras = set(record.__dict__.keys()) - default_attrs

        log_items = ['"message": "%(message)s"']
        for attr in extras:
            log_items.append(f'"{attr}": "%({attr})s"')
        format_str = f'{{{", ".join(log_items)}}}'
        self._style._fmt = format_str

        return super().format(record)


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = ExtraFormatter()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.info('hi')
logger.info('hi', extra={"user": "asmith", "number": "42"})
```

**Output**

```
{"message": "hi"}
{"message": "hi", "user": "asmith", "number": "42"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the CustomFormatter in the other answer, you can also pass a dictionary with default values to the formatter, starting with python 3.10: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('{"message": "%(message)s", "user": "%(user)s"}', defaults={"user":""})
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```