# Python Logging - How to log as JSON str?

Tags: python, json, python-logging

I have a Python Django app where we need to log using below code snippet to allow ELK to index the log record as `JSON`

```py
logger.info(json.dumps({'level':'INFO','data':'some random data'})
```

I have to use `json.dumps()` everytime . Is there a way in `logging` module to get rid of `json.dumps()` in every log message but still achieve the same functionality

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python logging into file as a dictionary or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144628/python-logging-into-file-as-a-dictionary-or-json)

Answer (score 1):

[python-json-logger](https://pypi.org/project/python-json-logger/)
do the job.

[this article](https://medium.com/swlh/python-async-logging-to-an-elk-stack-35498432cb0a) seems explain the approach to the solution.

You can customize the formatter, as suggested by [@NicoCaldo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7848740/nicocaldo)

or in general use any other format like a 'pipe separated format' to communicate to ELK  like in[this example](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/python+logging+to+elk)