# how to parse python dictionary in node js

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, parsing

i'm using node.js.
i have a python dictionary returned from elasticsearch log:

```js
{'name': 'dan',
 'age': 38,
 'color': 'green',
 'hobbies': None, 
 'message': 'this message has quotes in it \' so i cannot replace all single quotes', 
 'happy': True}
```

how can i parse this in javascript?
i have tried this regex solver but he could not deal with the True/False or None values, and kinda looks funky:

```js
 const regex = /('(?=(,\s*')))|('(?=:))|((?<=([:,]\s*))')|((?<={)')|('(?=}))/g;
str = str.replace(regex, '"');
str = JSON.parse(str);
```

any ideas would be very helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: Is there some way you can get it to log JSON instead of Python syntax?

Comment: The proper solution is to [make Python log as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48170682/1048572). Then you can parse the log using any language.