# W0703: Catching too general exception Exception (broad-except)

Tags: python, pylint

I'm using pylint to review one of my .py scripts and the below warning shows:

```
W0703: Catching too general exception Exception (broad-except)
```

This is an extract of the code.

```
try:
    # Execute function1
    function1()
    logger.info('Function 1 successfully executed')
    
except Exception as e:
    send_mail_error(str(e))
    logger.error(str(e))
```

I would like to understand what is pylint suggesting here in order to improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good practice to catch specific exception, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990718/about-catching-any-exception).

In your case you want to log unknown exception and send email. In such case I am using `SMTPHandler` and custom `sys.excepthook` - [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16993115/10536858).

Comment: Ok, so if I'm understanding correctly, instead of catching all exception, it's better practice to go one by one through Value Error, IO Error... and put a specific message for each?

Comment: Yes, it is. Read Blaze's comment under best answer of first question I linked. "... it's good to track down as many as you can and handle them appropriately and then have a backup catch all for the ones you miss."