# how to format exception which stopped the process?

Tags: python, exception, logging

For example:

```
# foo.py
foo = 1
bar = foo + 2
raise ValueError("FIXME")
```

`python foo.py` will generate something like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/app/foo.py", line 3
     raise ValueError("FIXME")
```

But what if I want to format this error message into json string `{"exc_info": "Traceback...", "level": "ERROR", ...}`. Can I do this using `logging` module? I don't what to use `try/except` and `logging.exception`.

Comment: It sounds like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234405/logging-uncaught-exceptions-in-python) might be what you're looking for. You should be able to reformat the exception details in whatever way you like.

Comment: tnx, this is exactly what I needed